# How to turn off CPU cores on Samsung Galaxy A8?

Tags: cpu, samsung-galaxy-a8-2018

I need to turn off CPU cores in order to make energy measurements of sets of cpu cores in isolation (meaning that I want to run an application on a set of cpu cores and turn off the cpu cores that are not in the set). I looked at the documentation on the [android linux kernel source](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/android-4.4-p/Documentation/cpu-hotplug.txt) and it says the following:

> Q: How do i logically offline a CPU? 
>   A: Do the following. 
>       `#echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/online` 
>   Once the logical offline is successful, check 
>       `#cat /proc/interrupts` 
>   You should now not see the CPU that you removed. Also online file will report
>   the state as 0 when a cpu if offline and 1 when its online. 
>       #To display the current cpu state. 
>       `#cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/online`

But when I write 0 to the online file, it still reports the CPU as being online even with superuser permissions and marking the file as writable (`chmod +w`).

I imagine that the kernel is enabling the cpu again after I disabled it. Also I did not try to turn off CPU 0 because in the same documentation it says that it's not removable in some architectures, this behavior is happening on other CPUs.

Do I need to rebuild the kernel in order to enable the cpu hotplug or is this an architecture specific problem? Maybe my cpu doesn't support hotplugs.

**What I've tried by now**

- Writing to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuN/online` with a rooted device. (`echo "0" > ./sys/device/...../online`)
- Changing the kernel to a custom one and trying the step above again. (Kernel installed was Quantum Kernel)
- Using [kernel adiutor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grarak.kerneladiutor&hl=en) to turn off the CPUs on the CPU tab (this turns off the CPU for a while then it turns back on again)
- Using su on adb shell to change file permissions on sysfs (`chmod 664 /sys/devices/...../online`) and then trying to write to it.

**Device Information** 
**Model:** Samsung Galaxy A8 (SM-A530F) 
**Android Version:** Android Pie (9) 
**Kernel:** Quantum Kernel V4 
**Kernel version:** 4.4.111-Quantum_pie.V4.0-A530F 
**Processor:** Samsung Exynos Octa 7885 
**Architecture:** aarch64

EDIT: Forgot to mention that my device is rooted.

Answer (score 0):

This helps on Galaxy-S7:

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuhotplug/enabled
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online
```